# Facebook returning error 500 with Koala Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I'm trying to put a connection from a rails app, i am using a custom object with custom actions i have set up within facebook open graph dashboard (in the developer area).

in my application controller i have the following;

```
def graph
   Koala::Facebook::API.new(cookies[:access_token]) unless cookies[:access_token].nil?
end
```

And in my create method after i have saved the @submission record i have the following;

```
graph.put_connections("me", "myappsnamespace:start", :submission => submission_path(@submission, :only_path => false))
```

Every time it gets to the line of code above i receive an error;

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError Exception: HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}
```

If i check the submission path with the Open Graph Object debugger it returns no errors and all the appropriate meta property tags are there.

The appropriate scope for Facebook has been set-up in the initializer.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you figure this out. I'm having same issue. Beating my head for a couple hours now.

Answer (score 0):

graph.put_connections's sample:

`@graph.put_connections("me", "notes", :subject => "Finding my mom a gift: An Epic Odyssey", :message => all_the_details)`

`@graph.put_connections("me", "feed?message=foo%0D%0Abar")`

But what's `"myappsnamespace:start"`?

[Koala's Graph-API Wiki](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API)